# Did Gandhi supporters block trains by lying down in front of them?

Tags: india, mahatma-gandhi

Many websites and history books report that ([example](https://www.q-files.com/history/famous-leaders/mahatma-gandhi/) ) but I couldn't find any documentation of the time (photos, newspaper articles, etc...)

Comment: You find a scene with protesters disrupting rail service in the movie [Bhowani Junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhowani_Junction_%28film%29), with Ava Gardner and Stewart Granger, directed by George Cukor. Fiction or not?

Comment: The [Gandhi biography by Christine Jordis](https://books.google.fr/books?id=QvNf_0ayblMC&pg=PT122&lpg=PT122&dq=Gandhi+manifestation+trains+voies&source=bl&ots=gzh420j8ro&sig=Yz_zhWQssSpiZKUh8rVBXFVz7iQ&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG17vCtsPKAhWFfxoKHReCDDAQ6AEIJjAB#v=onepage&q=Gandhi%20manifestation%20trains%20voies&f=false) only refers to villagers saying that, if Gandhi train didn't stop in their small station, they would lie down on railway rails.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [World Diary 1929-1934](http://www.shellnews.net/documents/WorldDiary1934Com.pdf) at page 35:

> On April 5 [1930] Gandhi carried out his threat... Within a week British soldiers throughout India were using their swagger sticks to flick the white cotton caps off the heads of Gandhi's supporters, who were obstructing
>   traffic by lying down on railway tracks and public thoroughfares...

Similarly, according to the [New International Yearbook](https://books.google.com/books?id=5YNMAAAAMAAJ&q=gandhi%20lay%20across%20tracks&dq=gandhi%20lay%20across%20tracks&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisic__h8XKAhXisYMKHZ_1CscQ6AEIHDAA) at page 365:

> His act of open defiance of the Government took place on April 6...railway employees quit their work and in some cases lay across the tracks to obstruct traffic

See also [Demand for Special Train: Nationalists Lie down on Line](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/46363233?searchTerm=Gandhi%20%22railway%20tracks%22&searchLimits=dateFrom=1929-01-01%7C%7C%7CdateTo=1948-12-31) The West Australian 19 March 1940 page 8

> 200 Nationalists lay down on the railway track in front of a train near Calcutta